# How to assign task for each thread without forcefully using c I.e each thread need to take some work after completion of first work ?

Tags: c, pthreads

I.e each thread need to take some work after completion of first work. Automatically each thread need to take task and run the code. can some please help on this method ?

```
    #include <pthread.h>


    #define thread_count (4)
    pthread_t read_thread_id[thread_count ];

    float sum_Data[128]= {0,1,2,3.........128};
    float sub_Data[128]= {0,1,2,3.........128};
    float Out_Mem[128] ={0};




    void af_sum(float *a, float *b, float *c)
    {
       c=a+b;
       return 0;
    }

    void *Data_output(void *data)
    {
       int temp = (int) data;
       int k;

       if(temp==0)
       {
//assigning some task for thread 0
          for(k = 0; k < 32; k++)
          {
             af_sum(&sum_Data[k], &sub_Data[k], &Out_Mem[k]);
          }
       }
       else if(temp==1)
       {
//assigning some task for thread 1
          for(k = 32; k < 64; k++)
          {
             af_sum(&sum_Data[k], &sub_Data[k], &Out_Mem[k]);
          }
       }
       else if(temp==2)
       {
//assigning some task for thread 3
          for(k = 64; k < 96; k++)
          {
             af_sum(&sum_Data[k], &sub_Data[k], &Out_Mem[k]);
          }
       }
       else
       {
//assigning some task for thread 4
          for(k = 96; k < 128; k++)
          {
             af_sum(&sum_Data[k], &sub_Data[k], &Out_Mem[k]);
          }
       }

       return 0;

    }



    int main()
    {

       int i,k;
       for (i = 0; i < thread_count ; i++)
       {
          pthread_create (&read_thread_id[i], NULL, Data_output, (void *) i);
       }

       for (i = 0; i < AF_NUM_INSTANCE; i++)
       {
          pthread_join (read_thread_id[i], NULL);

       }

        return (0);
    }
```

I.e each thread need to take some work after completion of first work. Automatically each thread need to take task and run the code.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. You can use different thread functions for different threads.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function that is called by all the threads to pick up the work.  The pick_work() function uses mutex to ensure that each threads gets its own unique work.  Here's the pseudocode:

```
int currWork = 0;

// Each thread calls pick_work() to figure out the work.  If the
// return value of pick_work() is < 0, the thread returns/exits.

// Returns index of work assgined to caller
// Returns -1 to indicate that there is no more work left.
int pick_work()
{
    int work_index = -1;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    if (currWork < MAX_WORKS) {
        work_index = currWork;
        currWork++;
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    return work_index;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your problem, it seems you have a different range of **k** for each thread. So, you don't need a mutex for calculating the value of k. The only thing needed is to send the start and end value of k for each thread, which is passed to af_sum function.

Since we cannot pass multiple arguments to a thread function, need to use a structure to group all the arguments. Will be using a pointer to the structure as an argument to the thread function.

Following changes are needed

```
    typedef struct dataStruct
    {
            int start;
            int end;
    }dataStruct;

    void *Data_output(void *data)
    {
            dataStruct *D = (dataStruct *)data;
            for(int k = D->start; k < D->end; k++)
                af_sum(&sum_Data[k], &sub_Data[k], &Out_Mem[k]);
    }

    int main()
    {
         pthread_t read_thread_id[4];
         dataStruct D[4] = {{0, 32}, {32, 64}, {64, 96}, {96, 128}};
         int i;
         for (i = 0; i < thread_count ; i++)
         {
            pthread_create (&read_thread_id[i], NULL, Data_output, (void *) &D[i]);
         }

         for (i = 0; i < thread_count; i++)
         {
            pthread_join (read_thread_id[i], NULL);
         }
         return (0);
    }
```